# iPhone access to local web server through USB connection on Linux

Tags: ios, iphone, nginx

I'm running a Nginx Web server on my Linux system and I would like to access it on my iPhone (Safari or through my iOS app) when I connect it through USB cable.
How can I do it? is there any available solution?

Having iPhone and Linux system in a same network and access through its iP is not a solution here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ngrok](https://ngrok.com).
Here is a step-by-step guide:

1. Download ngrok (https://ngrok.com/download) and move executable to `/usr/bin/`.
2. Register [here](https://dashboard.ngrok.com/signup) and copy your auth token.
3. Open the terminal (<kbd>Ctrl+Alt+T</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+F3</kbd>) and type:

```sh
cd
ngrok authtoken <YOUR_AUTHTOKEN>
ngrok http 80
```

It will give you some URL address. Open it on your iPhone.
Your home page will be shown.
More info on ngrok: https://ngrok.com/docs/secure-tunnels